# Serialization of ArrayList in Android

Tags: android

I have been having problems with my app. On exit from an activity a call is made to serialize an arrayList of objects. On starting the app from scratch a call is made to deserialize. This doesn't work but when i designed the code prior to integrating it with android it worked fine. I have included my serialization code as well as the exit code from the activity and the on create code from the main activity. maybe someone can spot something obvious that is going wrong. Many thanks.

```
public class MainBudgetLogin extends Activity  {

    public static int studentNo;
    public static int loginNo;
   private TextView attempts;
   private Button login;
   int counter = 3;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      AccountSerialize.deSerialize();
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);      
      attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
      login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);

   }

       public void exit3(View view){

           AccountSerialize.serialize();
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainBudgetLogin.class);        
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           startActivity(intent);          
           finish();
       }

public class AccountSerialize {
    public static String filename ="serialized3";
    //public static String tmp;

    public static void serialize(){
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("serialized3");
            ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(MainBudgetAddOrSpend.transactions);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();           
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();            
        }//System.out.println("Done writing");

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void deSerialize(){
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("serialized3");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            MainBudgetAddOrSpend.transactions = (ArrayList<AccountInfo>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
            //System.out.println("Class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: To see the errors, do not ignore exceptions at your serialize and deserialize methods. Or use Log.d and then look at the LogCat to see what is the reason of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The path you have specified is not valid for an android device. You don't have the right to write on `/`. You can use the external/internal flash to write/read file and you can use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to retrieve its path. For instance:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "serialized3") ;
FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(file);
```

remember that you have to declare the corresponding permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file to write into the  external/internal flash

Comment: Thanks for posting advice so quickly. Could you explain what you mean by 'declare the corresponding permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file to write into the external/internal flash'. I'm totally new to android so forgive my lack of understanding with this part. Regards Richard

Comment: It is ok, Here you can find what you need to know about the use-permission about android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

Comment: I read the link you provided and it said that after API 19 that it is no longer necessary to request permissions for external storage. I am using API 4.4.Does this mean that i dont need to ask permission or write anything in the manifest?

Comment: the device where you are running the app what version of android has?

Comment: I am just using a default emulator with eclipse, im not sure what the api is. On setting up the project i chose the 4.4 if that makes any difference.

Comment: there is no default emulator. You have to create one and there you can specify api level and the emulated sdcard. There is a big difference between the version against you are compiling and what the device/emulator supports